# Screen reader is not announcing the title of the page

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, jaws-screen-reader, nvda, react-helmet

I am developing a single-page application that has multiple components in react. The react project is set up on top of the spring boot application.

I am setting the title inside the useEffect using *document.title = "title";*
But the screen readers are not announcing the title of the page when the page is loaded or the title of the page has been changed.
I tried to set the title using  and , but both of them failed to announce the title of the page, even though the title is set.

Can someone help me to make the screen readers announce the title of the page whenever the title changes?

The screen readers used are *JAWS*, *NVDA*, *VoiceOver*.
Browsers: Chrome and firefox

Comment: If the page is not re-loading, then a screen reader is not going to re-announce the title element. It only gets announced once on page load. See here: https://webaim.org/techniques/screenreader/#how

Comment: Thanks for the update @Josh. In that case what do you think is the right way to announce the page getting updated after edit? And also, should we not announce the title of the page whenever the title changes. Will that not be a a11y compliance if title is not announced whenever it is changed?

Comment: I've seen some hacky workarounds trying to force the title element to be re-announced on change, but I wouldn't bother with things like that. It's almost like trying to simulate a multi-page application. You're already updating the title, which is good -- it provides a visual que to sighted users, and the title will be re-announced if the browser tab loses and regains focus. As long as you are ensuring the visitor is made aware of the change to the page (either through setting focus to some sensible location or through a live-region), then you should probably be okay.